# Solr faceting returning the average and the count

Tags: solr, faceted-search, geohashing

I'm using Solr 4.10 to apply the geohashing technique to create clusters of markers to display on a map.
My documents represent locations on a map, and each document has a multivalue field with the geohashes per zoom level. The solutions is as described [here](http://tech.willhaben.at/2015/07/geo-clustering-3000000-points-on-fly.html).

I'm using faceting to generate the clusters, which returns me a list of pairs with the geohash and the number of documents that have the given geohash. Since the geohashes represent the clusters, then I convert the geohash to lat/lng values and those are the coordinates where I place my clusters.

**Is it possible to make the facet return the average of a field alongside the count?** Basically I want to determine the cluster position through the average of each latitude and longitude of the markers that belong to the cluster.
I know that since Solr 5.1 we can use [facet functions](http://yonik.com/solr-facet-functions/) but I'm stuck to the 4.10 version.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [facet functions](http://yonik.com/solr-facet-functions/) is available only from Solr 5.1. With this feature you can return more than one metric per facet, like average, sum, min, max, etc..